# Specify generic type based on constructor signature

Tags: python, typing

I have a function that takes a generic argument used for type-casting purposes (I know Python doesn't do those but humor me here). Essentially, this function can accept any type that has a constructor which can accept `self` alone. I want to do something like this:

```
T = TypeVar("T")  # Annotation here

def some_func(x: Type[T]) -> T:
    return x(do_something_else())
```

Obviously, this is an over-simplified example, but I'm not sure how to specify the type here. `x` could be `str`, `int`, a class type or anything else.

If I were to annotate `x` with `Callable[[Any], T]` then I couldn't submit `int` or `str` as arguments because these aren't technically callables, they're types. However, if I submit `Type[T]` as an argument then mypy will complain that there are too many arguments for object, as described in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/10343).

So, how do I annotate based on the signature of a type's `__init__` method?

Comment: what isn't working with your solution?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I want to type-annotate `x` but mypy complains about it.

Comment: **why is the complaint**? Why do you omit this information?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had included it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have updated the question to include more details regarding the issue.

Comment: OK, thank you. I really encourage you to provide an actualy [mcve]. Something we can *copy and paste and run mypy*, and then provide the *actual output* (again, copy-and-pasted).

Anyway, note, `str` and `int` are very much technically callables, so that approach should work. All types are callable, precisely because `type` defines a `__call__` method.

Comment: But, I would annotate it with `typing.Callable[[Foo], T]` where `Foo` is the return type of `do_something_else()` if you want it to be type safe

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sorry, I think this issue is a bit deeper than I had originally described so I'll be closing this question. All part of the process and I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, my assertion that I couldn't annotate with `Callable[[Any], T]` was incorrect because `str` and `int` do qualify for this annotation:

```
def some_func(x: Callable[[Any], T]) -> T:
    return x(do_something_else())
```